# How do I export content from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, export

Is there any way to export all the Facebook historical data from your profile (contacts, photos, videos, posts, links, comments, etc.) to a local storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [web app](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13993/) describes steps to achieve what you're looking for I think.

**Update**

It appears this addon was removed.  It used to be called ArchiveFacebook, but I don't see it on the mozilla site anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Facebook now lets you do this directly from their site.

1. Go to "[Account Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings)"
2. Click on "General" in left hand navigation
3. Look for "Download a copy of your Facebook data." underneath  *name, username, ..., temperature* table.

It gives a message about how it will take a while to package it all up. Your password is needed to begin the archive process. An e-mail will be sent when your download is ready to go, and then you'll need to verify your identity again in order to download the archive.